# PHP not working in chrome properly

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

My PHP code is working fine in Firefox Mozilla but not in google chrome. My code is given below.

PHP:

```
$fee=0;
if($_POST['amount'])
{
    $fee=$_POST['amount'];  
}

else if($_POST['payprice'])
{
    $fee=$_POST['payprice'];    
}

else if($_POST['regfee'])
{
    $fee=$_POST['regfee'];  
}

else
{
    $fee=0;
}
```

JavaScript Code

```
function submitpay()
{
    document.forms[0].submit(); 
}

setInterval("submitpay()", 100));
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="../customerpg/pg1/check.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="showupdt" value="block" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $fee; ?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean `works` and `doesn't work`? Is there an error?

Comment: PHP code works on server and knows __nothing__ about your browser. Open developers console and monitor errors there.

Comment: @u_mulder ur burning everyone today lol

Comment: Javascript setInterval is not working properly

Comment: my guess: `submitpay` is fired before dom is ready. Increase the milliseconds or wrap it in an window.onload or smth.

Comment: and the 1st param of setinterval should be the actual function, not a string with the name of the function.

Comment: Jeff you are right. code is working now.  thanks

Comment: PHP works server-side and has nothing to do with your browser. The problem is your javascript. Use `setInterval(submitpay, 100)`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
setInterval(submitpay, 100);
```

instead of

```
setInterval("submitpay()", 100)
```

Firstly I don't think you can send the function call as a string. Secondly don't put `()` at the end of the function - that will execute the function immediately, and it will be the *result* of the function which is passed into setInterval (and unless that result is itself a reference to a function, it won't work). What you should pass is a *reference* to the function, by using its name.

And in future, check your browser console (press F12 for the developer tools) for errors before you do anything else. This will give you a big clue as to what is happening in cases like these. Usually you can even click on the line number of the code which is failing and see exactly where the problem is.

Lastly, a technical point regarding your question wording. It's not the *PHP* which isn't working, since PHP runs on the server, it's the JavaScript (which may, or may not, have been generated by some PHP that you wrote, but that's irrelevant in this case) which is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible.

One case which I had encountered, and might as well fix your problem.

Case: The code is run on subdomain in localhost, like `http://subdomain.localhost/project/` and some proxy plugin (Browsec, Ultrasurf) is running.

In this case, the code won't run. You can stop the plugin, in order for it to work.